# Android Service

Tags: android, service

Please explain an Android `Service`. How does it differ from an `Activity`?  Does it depend on an application state such as running in the **foreground/background**?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

From the [Android Developer's SDK reference for Service](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html):

> A Service is an application component representing either an application's desire to perform a longer-running operation while not interacting with the user or to supply functionality for other applications to use.

It is very important to note

> that services, like other application objects, run in the main thread of their hosting process. This means that, if your service is going to do any CPU intensive (such as MP3 playback) or blocking (such as networking) operations, it should spawn its own thread in which to do that work.

This is in contrast to an activity which is best understood as something a user directly sees and interacts with (a UI.)

A service, as mentioned above, can be used for longer-running operations that will continue even if you have no foreground activity, but they can, and eventually will be killed by Android's lifecycle if left in the "background" state. If you need your service to continue running as a single instance without being killed and restarted, I would recommend placing [startForeground(int id, Notification notification)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#startForeground%28int,android.app.Notification%29) in your Service's `onCreate` method and [stopForeground(boolean removeNotification)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#stopForeground%28boolean%29) in your Service's `onDestroy` method.

For example, I have an app that uses a `foreground Service` to record accelerometer data all night while the android device is next to the user's body. Though it is not required to be active, I also have an `Activity` that broadcast an `Intent` to a `BroadcastReceiver` inside the `Service` which tells the `Service` that it should also broadcast an `Intent` with accelerometer data as extras to a `BroadcastReceiver` inside the `Activity`.

Code:
[SleepActivity](https://code.google.com/p/electricsleep/source/browse/beta/src/com/androsz/electricsleepbeta/app/SleepActivity.java)
[SleepAccelerometerService](https://code.google.com/p/electricsleep/source/browse/beta/src/com/androsz/electricsleepbeta/app/SleepMonitoringService.java)

Good luck and let me know if you need any more information!

Comment: your second link "SleepAccelerometerService" is broken.

Comment: Do you need to use some sort of WakeLock to keep your service running even when the phone goes to sleep?

Comment: Please note that for every long-running and cpu-intensive operationeyou may want to run your service code in a new thread since Services by default run and live in the UI Thread. You can use IntentService for most of your needs. HandlerThread and ThreadPoolExecutor are more flexible but more complex alternatives.

Answer (score 4):

a Service is a context similar to Activity but has no GUI.

Important: A service doesn't run in a new thread!

Read about [Service](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html) and also check out [How to always run a service in the background?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2566350/how-to-always-run-a-service-in-the-background)