# Android - Run a service in background even when app is killed or device rebooted

Tags: android, service, broadcastreceiver

I want to keep a service running in background, even when my app is killed. I'm using `android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT` event but the service only runs when the screen is unlocked. I tried `android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED` but it needs to restarts the phone at least once after downloading the app.

Ideally I would start my service all X minutes, using `ACTION_TIME_TICK` for instance. Then check conditions (battery level, network connections...) before starting the service.

The problem is such event can't be declared and listened from `manifest.xml` but rather in an Activity, implying the app to be 'alive'.

Is there a way to do what I want anyway ?

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15758980/android-service-need-to-run-alwaysnever-pause-or-stop I don<t know if it will work now because of the update that have been done on android, you might have to install your application as a system app to get this right now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

take a [look at `AlarmManager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html), which you can use to ensure your service is alive and well, if not, start/restart as needed.

You can register for AlarmManager the first time your app is opened after its installation. From then on, say if user reboots, register your service with `AlarmManager` using another (2nd) bootstrap service that  listens to `android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED`.

There may be other [considerations with device sleep](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15758980/android-service-need-to-run-alwaysnever-pause-or-stop), and the amount/kind of work you do in your background service, [take a look at this lib and notes as well](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-wakeful)

`AlarmManager` can continuously ensure your background service is healthy.

Comment: Thanks for comment but it seems that AlarmManager needs to be set from an activity as well.

Comment: so you want a background service started immediately after a user installs your apk but doesn't start/open the app (there is no killing, yet)

Comment: Ideally, yes. I don't mind if the user have to launch the app at least once but I'd like to start the service in background regularly even if killed, like I do with USER_PRESENT

Comment: opened once, but on reboot, you want it to start automatically without any other actions or further opening.

Comment: Yep, I know it isn't recommended but I'd like to.