# run app in background android

Tags: android, background, location, updates

i build app for location manager.i have a one method which give me lattitute and longitude.

Here are my class and activity.

GPStracker.java

```
public class GPSTracker extends Service implements LocationListener {

private final Context mContext;
private final Handler _handler = new Handler();
private static int DATA_INTERVAL = 1 * 60 * 1000;

// flag for GPS status
boolean isGPSEnabled = false;

// flag for network status
boolean isNetworkEnabled = false;

// flag for GPS status
boolean canGetLocation = false;

Location location; // location
double latitude; // latitude
double longitude; // longitude

// The minimum distance to change Updates in meters
private static final long MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES = 10; // 10 meters

// The minimum time between updates in milliseconds
private static final long MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES = 1000 * 60 * 1; // 1 minute

// Declaring a Location Manager
protected LocationManager locationManager;

public GPSTracker(Context context) {
    this.mContext = context;
    getLocation();
}

public Location getLocation() {
    try {
        locationManager = (LocationManager) mContext
                .getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

        // getting GPS status
        isGPSEnabled = locationManager
                .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

        // getting network status
        isNetworkEnabled = locationManager
                .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

        if (!isGPSEnabled && !isNetworkEnabled) {
            // no network provider is enabled
        } else {
            this.canGetLocation = true;
            if (isNetworkEnabled) {
                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                        LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,
                        MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                        MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                Log.d("Network", "Network");
                if (locationManager != null) {
                    location = locationManager
                            .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
                    if (location != null) {
                        latitude = location.getLatitude();
                        longitude = location.getLongitude();
                    }
                }
            }
            // if GPS Enabled get lat/long using GPS Services
            if (isGPSEnabled) {
                if (location == null) {
                    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                            LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                            MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                            MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                    Log.d("GPS Enabled", "GPS Enabled");
                    if (locationManager != null) {
                        location = locationManager
                                .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                        if (location != null) {
                            latitude = location.getLatitude();
                            longitude = location.getLongitude();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return location;
}

/**
 * Stop using GPS listener
 * Calling this function will stop using GPS in your app
 * */
public void stopUsingGPS(){
    if(locationManager != null){
        locationManager.removeUpdates(GPSTracker.this);
    }       
}

/**
 * Function to get latitude
 * */
public double getLatitude(){
    if(location != null){
        latitude = location.getLatitude();
    }

    // return latitude
    return latitude;
}

/**
 * Function to get longitude
 * */
public double getLongitude(){
    if(location != null){
        longitude = location.getLongitude();
    }

    // return longitude
    return longitude;
}



/**
 * Function to check GPS/wifi enabled
 * @return boolean
 * */
public boolean canGetLocation() {
    return this.canGetLocation;
}

/**
 * Function to show settings alert dialog
 * On pressing Settings button will lauch Settings Options
 * */
public void showSettingsAlert(){
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);

    // Setting Dialog Title
    alertDialog.setTitle("GPS is settings");

    // Setting Dialog Message
    alertDialog.setMessage("GPS is not enabled. Do you want to go to settings menu?");

    // On pressing Settings button
    alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Settings", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int which) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
            mContext.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    // on pressing cancel button
    alertDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        dialog.cancel();
        }
    });

    // Showing Alert Message
    alertDialog.show();
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {



}
public void notifyUser() {
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    Intent intent = new Intent(GPSTracker.this, AndroidGPSTrackingActivity.class);

    //use the flag FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT to override any notification already there
    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.ic_launcher, "Some Text", System.currentTimeMillis());
    notification.flags = Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL | Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS | Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;

    notification.setLatestEventInfo(this, "", "", contentIntent);
    //10 is a random number I chose to act as the id for this notification
    notificationManager.notify(10, notification);
}


@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
    return null;
}

}
```

AndroidGPSTrackingActivity.java

```
public class AndroidGPSTrackingActivity extends Activity {

Button btnShowLocation;

Geocoder geocoder;
List<Address> addresses;
private final Handler _handler = new Handler();
private static int DATA_INTERVAL = 1 * 60 * 1000;
// GPSTracker class
GPSTracker gps;
double longitude;
double latitude;
String address,city,state,country,postalCode,knownName,city2;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    geocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());

    location();


    btnShowLocation = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnShowLocation);

    // show location button click event
    btnShowLocation.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {        
            // create class object

            location();
        }
    });
}


public void location(){

    gps = new GPSTracker(AndroidGPSTrackingActivity.this);

    // check if GPS enabled
    if(gps.canGetLocation()){

        latitude = gps.getLatitude();
        longitude = gps.getLongitude();
        try {
            addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 1);
            Log.d("adddd", String.valueOf(addresses));
            address = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(0);
            city = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(1);
            state = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(2);


        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        // \n is for new line
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your Location is - \nLat: " + latitude + "\nLong: " + longitude + address + "\n"
                +city +" "+ state
                , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        _handler.postDelayed(getData, DATA_INTERVAL);
    }else{
        // can't get location
        // GPS or Network is not enabled
        // Ask user to enable GPS/network in settings
        gps.showSettingsAlert();
    }


}

public void notifyUser() {
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    Intent intent = new Intent(AndroidGPSTrackingActivity.this, AndroidGPSTrackingActivity.class);

    //use the flag FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT to override any notification already there
    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.ic_launcher, "Some Text", System.currentTimeMillis());
    notification.flags = Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL | Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS | Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;

    notification.setLatestEventInfo(this, city, state, contentIntent);
    //10 is a random number I chose to act as the id for this notification
    notificationManager.notify(10, notification);
}


private final Runnable getData = new Runnable()
{
    @Override
    public void run()
    {

        location();
        notifyUser();
    }
};



}
```

it gives me location from lattitute and longitute.

but when i terminate the app from recent app it does't work.
how to continue this (location()) method in background even if i terminate the app.

please help me.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Take a look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15758980/android-service-need-to-run-alwaysnever-pause-or-stop

Answer (score 0):

you can build remote service to get location info,remote service do not belong your app,it will not be terminated even your app is killed. you can bind remote service to get location info.

Comment: yes,give me link which give me guidelines of this. @simonws