# Run service even if the application is closed

Tags: java, android, service

My task is to run service even if app is closed.

My service class:

```java
public class MyService extends Service {

    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        AudioManager am;
        am= (AudioManager) this.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
            if(am.getRingerMode() == AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_NORMAL)
        am.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT);
            else
            am.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_NORMAL);
        Minute minute = new Minute();
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        AlarmManager alarms ;
        Intent activate = new Intent(this, MyService.class);
        PendingIntent alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, activate, 0);
        alarms = (AlarmManager) this.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 00);
        cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute.minute);
        cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 00);
        alarms.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), alarmIntent);
        Toast.makeText(this, "checkOnStart", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        return Service.START_STICKY;
    }
}
```

In my activity:

```
Intent activate = new Intent(this, MyService.class);
startService(activate);
```

But when I kill the app the service closed, what should I do to keep the service running after the app is killed?

Comment: have you found any solution ? i'm having the same problem

Answer (score 0):

It could be achieve by calling the service itself when it will be killed. But I can't really sure about it because I never trying it.

This article could be a help:
[Creating an never ending background service in android](http://fabcirablog.weebly.com/blog/creating-a-never-ending-background-service-in-android)

Read the similar question and answers at [Android Service need to run always(Never pause or stop)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15758980/android-service-need-to-run-alwaysnever-pause-or-stop)

-- Edited --

Here to near complete implementation from the article:

Manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="oak.shef.ac.uk.testrunningservicesbackgroundrelaunched">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <service
            android:name="oak.shef.ac.uk.testrunningservicesbackgroundrelaunched.SensorService"
            android:enabled="true" >
        </service>

        <receiver
            android:name="oak.shef.ac.uk.testrunningservicesbackgroundrelaunched.SensorRestarterBroadcastReceiver"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true"
            android:label="RestartServiceWhenStopped">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="uk.ac.shef.oak.ActivityRecognition.RestartSensor"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

MainActivity

```
import android.app.ActivityManager;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Intent mServiceIntent;
    private SensorService mSensorService;
    Context ctx;
    public Context getCtx() {
        return ctx;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        ctx = this;
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mSensorService = new SensorService(getCtx());
        mServiceIntent = new Intent(getCtx(), mSensorService.getClass());
        if (!isMyServiceRunning(mSensorService.getClass())) {
            startService(mServiceIntent);
        }
    }

    private boolean isMyServiceRunning(Class<?> serviceClass) {
        ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        for (ActivityManager.RunningServiceInfo service : manager.getRunningServices(Integer.MAX_VALUE)) {
            if (serviceClass.getName().equals(service.service.getClassName())) {
                Log.i ("isMyServiceRunning?", true+"");
                return true;
            }
        }
        Log.i ("isMyServiceRunning?", false+"");
        return false;
    }


    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        stopService(mServiceIntent);
        Log.i("MAINACT", "onDestroy!");
        super.onDestroy();

    }
}
```

Service

```
    import android.app.Service;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.os.IBinder;
    import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
    import android.util.Log;

    import java.util.Timer;
    import java.util.TimerTask;

    /**
     * Created by fabio on 30/01/2016.
     */
    public class SensorService extends Service {
        public int counter=0;
        public SensorService(Context applicationContext) {
            super();
            Log.i("HERE", "here I am!");
        }

        public SensorService() {
        }
        @Override
        public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
            super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
            startTimer();
            return START_STICKY;
        }
      @Override
        public void onDestroy() {
            super.onDestroy();
            Log.i("EXIT", "ondestroy!");
            Intent broadcastIntent = new Intent("uk.ac.shef.oak.ActivityRecognition.RestartSensor");
            sendBroadcast(broadcastIntent);
            stoptimertask();
        }

        private Timer timer;
        private TimerTask timerTask;
        long oldTime=0;
        public void startTimer() {
            //set a new Timer
            timer = new Timer();

            //initialize the TimerTask's job
            initializeTimerTask();

            //schedule the timer, to wake up every 1 second
            timer.schedule(timerTask, 1000, 1000); //
        }

        /**
         * it sets the timer to print the counter every x seconds 
         */
        public void initializeTimerTask() {
            timerTask = new TimerTask() {
                public void run() {
                   Log.i("in timer", "in timer ++++  "+ (counter++));
                }
            };
        }

        /**
         * not needed
         */
        public void stoptimertask() {
            //stop the timer, if it's not already null
            if (timer != null) {
                timer.cancel();
                timer = null;
            }
        }

        @Nullable
        @Override
        public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Service Restarter

```
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;

public class SensorRestarterBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.i(SensorRestarterBroadcastReceiver.class.getSimpleName(), "Service Stops! Oooooooooooooppppssssss!!!!");
        context.startService(new Intent(context, SensorService.class));;
    }
}
```

The service sends a message to the BroadcastReceiver which will restart the service after the service stop (it is an asynchronous call so it will not be affected by the death of the service.

The complete source code is [here](http://fabcirablog.weebly.com/uploads/1/6/5/1/16516722/testrunningservicesbackgroundrelaunched.zip)