# Service needs to run Continuously when device is locked/enter into Doze Mode

Tags: android, background-service, doze

My App needs to run in background continuously to send the location updates to the server. I tried Timer , Job Scheduler with background service none of these didn't worked. Its working fine when device is active, after entering into Doze mode the timer which i used is getting paused. When the device is active the Timer is getting resumed.

Checked with this Permission also ACTION_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATION_SETTINGS.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android Service needs to run always (Never pause or stop)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15758980/android-service-needs-to-run-always-never-pause-or-stop)

Answer (score 0):

Post OREO there are limits to what you can do on a background thread

Create a foreground service. In which you will put notification for the user while your service is running.

Here is a StackOverflow answer which would help you create that foreground service
[Foreground Service](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15775964/13533028)

Comment: / @Anirudh,  addNotification() we need to define in onCreate() / onStartCommand() of the Service class?

Comment: yes .> or whenver you want the service to trigger