# Why a service can use the apllication resources even after the application is closed?

Tags: android, service

I have a widget with a service which uses resources from the main application. I want to know the functionality behind this.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4353570/android-service

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the service uses RemoteViews to access and use resources.