# My application is getting killed when removed from recent apps list

Tags: android, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

I want my app not to be get killed when user clears my apps screen shot from recent apps list from ICS.

Comment: ... well, yes, that's the point.

Answer (score 1):

You need a [service](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html).

See [How to always run a service in the background?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2566350/how-to-always-run-a-service-in-the-background)