# Android start service without starting application?

Tags: android, service

Is it possible to start service without starting application? I need to refresh data of my application at-least hourly, how can I do it if user no in my application?

Comment: possible duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2127044/how-to-start-android-service-on-installation

but yeah... there's no direct way of starting the service after installation. I haven't tried the solution mentioned there either, so I can't judge.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you can start your service on boot.
You need the following in your AndroidManifest.xml file:

1. In your <manifest> element:

   `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />`
2. In your <application> element (be sure to use a fully-qualified [or relative] class name for your BroadcastReceiver):

In MyBroadcastReceiver.java:

```
package com.example;

public class MyBroadcastreceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Intent startServiceIntent = new Intent(context, MyService.class);
        context.startService(startServiceIntent);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible.

You can read about different methods of doing so [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2566350/how-to-always-run-a-service-in-the-background).