# Open an application without adding an intent to the AndroidManifest file

Tags: android

I want to open an android application from my browser. I can't change anything on the app, so I can't change the AndroidManifest file unfortunately.

Comment: refer : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10945426/android-start-service-without-starting-application

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Make a link in the Android browser start up my app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3469908/make-a-link-in-the-android-browser-start-up-my-app)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may create another app with needed intent filter to catch 'view' intents and redirect those calls to your target app. You may create explicit intent with target activity class name.