# Refreshing token in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, oauth

I am developing a **Flutter** application and I am using **OAuth2** for authentication. The application can't be used if you are not logged in, it just shows a login screen and forces you to log in.

When I log in, I receive the following information from the authentication server:

- access token
- access token lifetime
- refresh token
- refresh token lifetime

When the access token is about to expire, I want to get a new one by sending refresh token to authentication server.

How would I implement the **refresh token mechanism**? I want to update the access token every time before it expires, even if user is **not using the application** (it is closed). If user needed to log in every time he opens the application, it would be very bad user experience. To avoid this, I want to refresh the token in background.

How can I achieve this to work on Android and iOS? Preferably without writing any native code for each of the platforms.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Future.delayed` to refresh the token before the expiration.

You can also run this part of code in background with [background processes](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/packages-and-plugins/background-processes) but your application must be in background.

Comment: So by default `Future.delayed` will not execute if app is closed?

Comment: Yes. I suppose you think about starting a service when the device boot to run code in background as possible solution. (https://stackoverflow.com/a/10945530/11577024)

I'm not sure that is possible without native code.

Comment: I have think about an alternative to your issue. You can also handling 401 http errors (token is expired), ask for a new token with the refresh token and try again your request. 
It consumes less battery and it also handles the case if the phone is off.

Comment: Great idea! Thank you, I will implement it this way.