# Automatically have an Android device connect & receive advertised data from BLE device

Tags: android

I have created an android application using android studio API 21 to scan & connect to a BLE device and subscribe to receive advertised data.  This works great, but now I would like to do this automatically without having the user to manually run the android application.  Is there a way for my android device to know when it is in range of the BLE device and to automatically connect and receive data if available?  I'm just a little confused as to what code is needed in the Broadcast receiver class and does the Broadcast receiver class need to be in a service?

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK, there is no such system broadcast for notifying BLE device found.
I think you will have to do it by yourself with a service

To scan BLE devices in background, you will have to run the scanning in a service.

Few requirements you may want.

1. **Start the service on app start**
   This is the starting point of your service first run.
   Just call startService in your activity onCreate.
2. **Keep service running**
   See, [how to keep service running](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12016623/android-service-always-keeps-running)
3. **Stop BLE scanning on bluetooth disabled**
   It is meaningless to keep scanning while bluetooth disabled by user.
   So, you may want this check. See, [detecting bluetooth change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9693755/detecting-state-changes-made-to-the-bluetoothadapter)
4. **Start the service on device boot**
   See, [start service at boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4562734/android-starting-service-at-boot-time)
5. **Implement BLE scan in service**
   Move all the code from your scanning activity (or fragment) to the service. Something like,

   ```
   BLEScanningService extends Service {

       @Override
       public int onStartCommand (Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
           if (/*Bluetooth is available*/) {
              /*
               Do BLE scan
               */
           } else {
              // Stop BLE scanning and stop this service
           }
       }
   }
   ```

Then, your will have BLE scanning service always running in background :)

Maybe you may also want to broadcast some event from the service so that app UI and notification can update correspondingly.

Comment: thxs for the feed back.  I'm going to do a little more research on when two devices are paired - bonded, to see if anything is triggered when they get into and out of range.