# How to check for inbox messages from remote server while application is not executing?

Tags: android, ios, delphi, push-notification, firemonkey

I will develop an app for iOS and Android using Delphi Seattle. My goal is that the user create some appointments in the database using the app, and later to be notified if his appointments were confirmed or rescheduled by the default notification center of each os platform.

**So what I want to do is to receive instant messages from the server without app being used at the moment by the user**, *just like when we receive messages from WhatsApp or Gmail frequently with opening them.*

*In windows I could install a service or tray application to execute when the OS starts*, **but how could I do that using a remote Windows Server running an WebBroker Standalone as API to comunicante to/from my mobile app?**

---

*Note:*
This question is not a replicate of other mentioned questions because it envolves doing something in Delphi's FMX Framework for Android and not the *Default Android Framework Library for Java*. The second thing is, I do not want to use Google Notifications Services.
All I want to do is an application that works as a Service in Android, just like windows does. But how create it and how to install it with the GUI application? Something like `public class LocationTrace extends Service` but for Delphi.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Keep Service running](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12016623/keep-service-running)

Comment: @NoChinDeluxe not duplicated, because here I need to make it work for Delphi's Firemonkey framework, NOT for Java.

Comment: The answer lies already in the tags: Push Notifications!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Delphi XE6 and above has support for push notifications.

Here's the official documentation:

[Mobile Tutorial: Using Remote Notifications (iOS and Android)](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Mobile_Tutorial:_Using_Remote_Notifications_%28iOS_and_Android%29)

There are also a lot of on-line resources for Delphi push notifications.