# Intents inside services

Tags: android, android-intent, service

I have a service class and inside a service class I have timer task class.

Can I pass an Intent from my service class to  other class which is in the service 
Reason - I need to use alarm manager just to fire timer task class from service, I want my service always to be running

```
public class TestService extends Service 
{

// I need to pass an intent to trigger alarm from TestService to timeTaskUpdate

 private class timeTaskUpdate extends TimerTask{ }


}
```

Comment: This question has been answered numerous times already: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2566350/how-to-always-run-a-service-in-the-background

Comment: That was for running services in background my question is - Can I pass an Intent from my service class to other class which is in the service and how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't send an Intent to a class that isn't an Android class. TimerTask is a Java class, not an Android class.

But why pass an Intent anyway? timeTaskUpdate is within the scope of TestService. You should be able to use a global variable within timeTaskUpdate. Intents are for communicating between Android components, which by definition are *not* in the same scope.

Having said this, you should be careful. Though I'm not familiar with TimerTask, it may run on a separate thread. If so, you should be sure that you handle concurrency.

Comment: Yes, you'll need to post the updates to the UI thread using a handler.

Comment: I was using timer task and timer before for scheduling, but sometimes my timer task is killed itself so I want to change my code to alarm manager. SO I was thinking to have an alarm manager within my service class and call the other class which as the code to execute when my alarm manager is triggered