# Using google location services

Tags: android, google-maps, geolocation, location, google-api

Aloha,

I'm working on an app that uses location data that should be stored it in a local database.
It would be nice if my location service could always run in the background
But [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2566350/how-to-always-run-a-service-in-the-background) does not seem to be possible.
I noticed that Google has its own location service that sends anonymous location data to google servers (if enabled). Since this service is certainly deeply rooted in the OS, I would like to know whether I could just ask the user to enable this service and access the location data via a Google API. I've searched for it but I have only found the 'standard location' libraries.

Otherwise I cannot be sure that every location change is noticed an stored in the database.
At the moment I would implement a BroadcastReceiver that gets noticed when the system has finished booting and that simply starts my own custom location service. But this service might get killed by the OS if memory is needed.

Cheers

DeepBlue

Answer (score 0):

You can setup a simple webpage which store the locations in the server's database. When a person tags a location in your app for example, then the link of your webpage (with 4 parameters: `user_ID`, `longitue`, `latitude`, `sequrity_key`) should be called back and then the position of the user stored in your database. You can use Google project hosting for creating the webpage and accessing MySQL.