# How to clear an app if it is running in background

Tags: java, android, android-activity

Hi i have implemented small timer app and i am starting that app when ever i get a cal and it is working fine, my problem is if i am playing with my timer app, in that time if i get call it will open a timer application and current one is going to background and new one coming to foreground and timer starting in both side, so i thought when ever i get a cal i need to check if application is already running in background, if it is running i need kill and start the new one, How to achieve this.

Code to start activity:

```
Intent it = new Intent("intent.my.action");
                it.putExtra("Call", "true");

                it.setComponent(new ComponentName(context.getPackageName(),CActivity.class.getName()));
                it.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                it.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_BROUGHT_TO_FRONT);
                it.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_RECEIVER_FOREGROUND);
                context.getApplicationContext().startActivity(it);
```

Comment: Create an application class if don't have and implements ActivityLifecycleCallbacks . It will give you callbacks for activity state. Manage your requirement in it.

Comment: Can u give reference links..?

Comment: http://vardhan-justlikethat.blogspot.in/2014/02/android-solution-to-detect-when-android.html

Comment: Sorry that blog is not as per my requirement, Anyway thanks :)