# Make my activity run in background to collect gps

Tags: android, background-process, android-gps

I've created android apps which will collect GPS and store in MySQL database. It manages to collect and store right now. But how I make the GPS collector, collect in the background even the apps are killed. I had coded the GPS collector in my main activity.

Comment: see this solution is useful
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34573109/how-to-make-an-android-app-to-always-run-in-background/34573169#34573169

Comment: See this solution is useful [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34573109/how-to-make-an-android-app-to-always-run-in-background/34573169#34573169](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34573109/how-to-make-an-android-app-to-always-run-in-background/34573169#34573169)

Answer (score 0):

Use

> Services

A Service is an application component that can perform long-running operations in the background, and it does not provide a user interface. Another application component can start a service, and it continues to run in the background even if the user switches to another application

Service can handle network transactions, play music, perform file I/O, or interact with a content provider, all from the background.

you can try this http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidServices/article.html

Comment: is there any other solution except service? cause I have all my GPS collector codded in the main activity. anyway thank you.