# Android Oreo background service is not working in doze mode?

Tags: android, service, android-8.0-oreo, android-intentservice, firebase-job-dispatcher

I am using background service to get user location and upload to server.

I have used one LocationTrack class which is extending Service class and AlramReciver which is extending BroadcastReciver.

I have added all permission in manifest and register AlarmReciver and LocationTracker class in manifest file.

But when app goes into DOZE mode then service is not working.

I have tried following links but its not working anyways.

1. [How to create background services for android Oreo without notifications like social networking applications Facebook, Messenger, Zalo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51908186/how-to-create-background-services-for-android-oreo-without-notifications-like-so)
2. [Background service for android oreo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47110489/background-service-for-android-oreo)
3. [Android Oreo killing background services and clears pending alarms, scheduled jobs after entering doze mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50504296/android-oreo-killing-background-services-and-clears-pending-alarms-scheduled-jo)
4. [Oreo - Starting a service in the foreground](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47611123/oreo-starting-a-service-in-the-foreground)
5. https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/doze-standby
6. https://android.jlelse.eu/keep-those-background-services-working-when-targeting-android-oreo-sdk-26-cbf6cc2bdb7f

7.https://developer.zebra.com/community/home/blog/2018/10/26/keeping-your-application-running-when-the-device-wants-to-sleep

I have tried Jobdispatcher also but nothing works out.

Possibly it seems duplicate question but i don't understands whats wrong with my Code.
Please help to get rid of this.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use firebase job dispatcher for background service which works on all versions of android and is handled by firebase.

[Check this answer with firebase job dispatcher](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52722211/foregroundservice-on-android-oreo-gets-killed/52722651#52722651)

Comment: Thanks @Amit Jandi for quick response. will follow this link and get back to you

Comment: so is it working or not...i'm using in my apps and it works perfectly..

Comment: nope. it's not working in doze mode. Do i need to add android:enable="true" property in manifest for Class which extend JobServices class