# Always run service in background as root on android

Tags: android, android-service, root, background-process, android-8.0-oreo

According to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34573109/how-to-make-an-android-app-to-always-run-in-background) after *Android Oreo*, *Google* introduced some background limitations so it's not possible to run a *Service* always in background without displaying a user notification.

Is it possible to achieve this with root privileges?

EDIT: I see that people are voting to close my question because apparently it looks like it's too broad, but I am running *LineageOS*, and I would like to put my app to run as system service if possible, and I think that this would be feasible without modifying the source code. For example when installing the OS, I could flash GApps, but it was optional, and they seem to have the functionality that I'm talking about. I am also not expecting you to do all my research for me, and I am willing to accept the answer that points me in the right direction.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's indeed an undocumented shell command, which can be used to white-list packages, by adding them to the global `location_background_throttle_package_whitelist` (I haven't tested it):

```
settings put global location_background_throttle_package_whitelist "package1,package2,package3"
```

^ this is for `location` services, but there might be further `background_throttle` settings available:

```
settings list global | grep background_throttle
```

Source: [XDA Developers](https://www.xda-developers.com/android-oreo-background-location-whitelist/).

---

Also in the [source code](https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_frameworks_base/search?q=Settings.Global&unscoped_q=Settings) I've only found these settings:

```
Settings.Global.LOCATION_BACKGROUND_THROTTLE_PACKAGE_WHITELIST
Settings.Global.LOCATION_BACKGROUND_THROTTLE_PROXIMITY_ALERT_INTERVAL_MS
Settings.Global.LOCATION_BACKGROUND_THROTTLE_INTERVAL_MS
```

The [documentation](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background#services) is clear about the fact that certain services are being added into a  *temporary* white-list. To find out what actually white-lists these services, one would have to dig further. These background service restriction is actually being described in [Context.java](https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/content/Context.java#L2851) ...while the methods annotated with `@UnsupportedAppUsage` are the ones which only the system uses.

---

The Firebase [WorkManager](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager) is still the best option available - or the underlying [JobIntentService](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/app/JobIntentService), which will still run as a regular background service < Android `O`. Flashing Android `N` or Lineage OS `14.1` would be a certain workaround, which is barely being considered.

The assumption that `root` permissions would provide super-powers might be a misconception. Permitting unfettered location access is still quite limited and even Google's own services are only *temporarily* white-listed. The only services excluded from these background execution restrictions would be Linux [system services](https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/os/SystemService.java), written in `C++` (which are running outside of the JVM) - while this is something very else than Android background services, written in `Java` (which are running inside the JVM and all extend the same restricted `Service` class).

Answer (score 1):

One technique I've found that works quite well is to use a bound service. No user notification required and since you never call startService(), it works on Oreo and higher. No root needed either. A good place to bind to a service that will always run is from your application object's onCreate() method. Whenever your app is running the service will be running.

Comment: this still does not meet the demand of **not** having to run the app... the problem is, that `JobScheduler` does not run tasks instantly & `ForegroundService` does not run in the background. `root` does not really help either, because `root` isn't `system`.

Comment: A boot receiver could be used to start the app process, which would then start (bind) the service. This would all happen without the user having to "run" the app.

Comment: This would still run the app in foreground. `WorkManager` (or the underlying `JobIntentService`) run in the background - and I'd still be waiting for a valid reason not to use them; especially since there is no real alternative, even if the execution may be delayed. Just imagine 20 apps would use your suggestion... then you can scroll through the notification panel; it does not scale too well.

Comment: The app would only run in the foreground if startForeground() was called from within the service. Until then a bound service would run in the background and there would be no notification displayed. I guess it all depends on the purpose of the service. I've used JobIntentService too, but that is used to execute a time limited task of some kind. I haven't found it useful for running a service always in the background like the question was asking. I'm assuming WorkManager is similar, although I've never used it.