# What is similar to VOIP push and call kit of iOS in android for calling

Tags: java, android, ios, voip, callkit

In iOS we I have implemented call kit with VOIP push using push kit. So How can we achieve same in android ?

I don't have idea that android does support pushkit like functionality to send voip push

Any help or suggestion or docs would be great

Comment: Android don't have any pushkit feature. You can achieve this by using android services

Comment: @M.HamzaRajput Thanks for your response. How can we handle this when app is locked. Like are we able to show the app calling screen even when device is locked and app is in killed state

Comment: You can add firebase sdk in your dependences and create a push notification receiver in your android app. When you get a push notification in your app you can awake you application with UI flags.

Answer (score 1):

**This might help.**

First you need to create a [push notification receiver](https://android.jlelse.eu/android-push-notification-using-firebase-and-advanced-rest-client-3858daff2f50) in your [service](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services). Here is [service exemple](https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/android-service-example/). While your application is background or destroyed. You can receive push notification from [receiver](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcasts). Then you can [start your activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34573109/how-to-make-an-android-app-to-always-run-in-background) as you want to start with [windows flags](https://www.codota.com/code/java/methods/android.view.Window/setFlags).

If you have a query you can ask.