# Unity Android app: How to run app in background?

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, multitasking

I'm working on a Unity app that targets Android as platform. It's necessary that this app continues to run even when it does not have the focus in Android. My research so far brought me these possibilities:

- Export the project as an Android gradle project and manimpulate the app's lifecycle in the `UnityPlayerActivity`, as described [here](https://forum.unity.com/threads/android-app-is-actually-running-in-background-it-work.443436/)
- Use a (native Android) *service*, as often described, e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34573109/how-to-make-an-android-app-to-always-run-in-background)

So far I have not succeeded in getting to run any of the options, so:
Is there any 'native' Unity way to achieve that the app runs in background? And are there conditions that my Unity app has to satisfy for this?

Comment: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Application-runInBackground.html
I found this , possible android and IOS can't do that

Comment: https://forum.unity.com/threads/application-runinbackground-is-not-working-on-android.117723/ Does not work indeed