# How i can run unity app in background on Android?

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, background

I have a problem, I need my Android app to stay active when it's in the background.

Application.runInBackground = true;

Answer (score 1):

Android application created by Unity can't run in background. [Application.runInBackground](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Application-runInBackground.html) is ignored on Android and iOS platforms. In case of Android, Unity app extend `Activity` class which run only when app in the focus. If you want run something in background you should extend and write logic in `Service` class. It`s good described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34573109/how-to-make-an-android-app-to-always-run-in-background). But for it need to write you own plugin or something similar to this.

Answer (score 1):

You can use UnityThread script, I've created Bluetooth low energy plugin that will continue to work within background in a new Thread.

Check this: https://github.com/222ZoDy222/Unity-Bluetooth-Low-Energy-Background-Andoid

- If you want your application to run in the background, but don't need it to work 24/7, then a new thread is enough for you.
- If you want to your application play 24/7, you should use Java services as stated above

Answer (score 0):

From [this unity question](https://forum.unity.com/threads/keep-editor-playing-when-not-in-focus.1024003/):

Project Settings, Player, Resolution and Presentation, check the Run in Background option.

Comment: There is no such section for Android applications

Comment: @Dimon What do you mean no such section? I don’t know of unity hiding options, because it can’t know beforehand which platforms it is building to.

Comment: I mean, that this function works only for pc

Comment: @Dimon Does it throw an error?

Comment: No, there is no "Run in Background option"

Comment: @Dimon Wow, didn’t know that could happen! Sorry, I can’t help you in that case.