# L2CAP communication in background mode

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth, l2cap

I tried to implement a simple demo application which handles communication with BLE devices while the application is put in background mode by the user. However, the communication seems to be suspended a couple seconds after the application is put in background.

I tried to document myself about L2CAP communication in the background and found some posts stating that L2CAP communication is not supported in the background. I wonder if someone has achieved what I'm trying to.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make an android app to always run in background?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34573109/how-to-make-an-android-app-to-always-run-in-background)

Comment: I have just seen that the question refers to ios. Therefore your application needs to instantiate a [BackgroundTask](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/app_and_environment/scenes/preparing_your_ui_to_run_in_the_background#3222193)

Comment: L2Cap is not supported in the background for extended periods.  You can use `beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler` to get up to 180 seconds of execution.

Comment: See my answer for an update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just upgraded my testing device to iOS 17, and BLE L2CAP CoC communication is working even when the application is in background.

No code has been modified so I guess L2CAP CoC background communication has been fixed by Apple in iOS 17.